# The font size of posts in the Android app is too small!

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, android-app, font-size

So I was browsing through my activity a little and went to visit the bigger 'problem points' of last week to check back upon myself and stumbled over [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29252788/1803692).

In my Android app that looks a little... small:

[image: screenshot of overly small text]

Poking around a little I found out that the codeblocks in that question are fully functional. And when I thought there was not much else I noticed I could scroll the post because of some overflowing text:

[image: scrolled post showing text passing a codeblock and extending the small post to the outside]

Comment: Sorry for the overly large screenshots. While cropping and drawing freehand circles is possible I was unable to resize the pictures :( edits welcome

Comment: suggested an edit - to make an image smaller, add an `s`, `m` or `l` at the end of the url for small, medium and large

Comment: Please remember that tgis is a bugreport and not a featurerequest...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I cannot reproduce this anymore with the latest version of the android app on that question.

I'm assuming [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

Comment: Not anymore :( http://imgur.com/aIH8wZ1

Comment: would you mind opening a new bug-report for that? Please mention app-version and which post this occured on. With a repro that would be perfect. Also you should mention this Q&A for reference. For me it didn't happen again, and I can't de-mark this as [tag:status-completed] ...

Comment: I can't do it now, i will try to find a moment later. And i am sure I know the exact sequence of steps to reproduce this bug.